# Take the dot product for each column with itself and store in new array dimension

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, linear-algebra

I need to take the dot-product of each column with the transpose of itself, in a given 2D array. Currently, I am using loops and it is slow and ugly so I am wondering how to do this with pure array operations (if possible) and e.g. using `einsum` and similar tools.

MWE:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.randint(2,15,size=(2,3))

>>>A
array([[14,  9,  4],
       [12,  8,  2]])
```

Here's what I want, including the way I am currently doing it:

```
AA = [A[:,i].reshape(-1,1).dot(A[:,i].reshape(-1,1).T) for i in range(3)]
>>>AA
[array([[196, 168],
        [168, 144]]),
 array([[81, 72],
        [72, 64]]),
 array([[16,  8],
        [ 8,  4]])]
```

And finally

```
>>>np.stack(AA,axis=0)
array([[[196, 168],
        [168, 144]],

       [[ 81,  72],
        [ 72,  64]],

       [[ 16,   8],
        [  8,   4]]])
```

which has shape `(3,2,2)`.

Now obviously in my real problem, `A` is huge so the current approach is not feasible. Hence how can this be done better?

Comment: Why do you want the size 3 dimension to be first, when its last with the input array?

Comment: Oh I don't need that at all, that was the first number (0) but it can go anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [numpy.einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```py
import numpy as np
A = np.array([
       [14,  9,  4],
       [12,  8,  2]
    ])

np.einsum('ik,jk->kij', A, A)
array([[[196, 168],
        [168, 144]],

       [[ 81,  72],
        [ 72,  64]],

       [[ 16,   8],
        [  8,   4]]])
```

Answer (score 2):

This is actually an kind of outer product, not a `dot`.  There's no summing of products - except for the new size 1 dimension that you create with reshape.

```
In [351]: A = np.array([
     ...:        [14,  9,  4],
     ...:        [12,  8,  2]
     ...:     ])
```

With the common broadcasted "outer" product:

```
In [352]: A[:,None,:]*A[None,:,:]
Out[352]: 
array([[[196,  81,  16],
        [168,  72,   8]],

       [[168,  72,   8],
        [144,  64,   4]]])
In [353]: _.shape
Out[353]: (2, 2, 3)
```

Those are the desired numbers, but with the '3' shape last, as in `A`.  We could transpose it.  Or transpose `A` first:

```
In [354]: A.T[:,None,:]*A.T[:,:,None]
Out[354]: 
array([[[196, 168],
        [168, 144]],

       [[ 81,  72],
        [ 72,  64]],

       [[ 16,   8],
        [  8,   4]]])
```